# Cannot invoke helper methods from classes defined within a helper file on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I was trying to create a little helper method to make it easier for me to create forms with ui-kit on rails

```rb
# app/helpers/form_helper.rb
module FormHelper
  def styled_form_for(record)
    form_for record do |form|
      builder = StyledFormBuilder.new(form)

      yield form, builder
    end
  end

  class StyledFormBuilder
    def initialize(form)
      @form = form
      @obj = form.object
    end

    def text_field(field, **props)
      styled_field :field do
        @form.text_field field, class: ['uk-input', @obj.errors[field].any? && 'uk-form-danger', *props.class],
                                **props
      end
    end

    private

    def styled_field(field)
      errors = @form.object.errors[field].map do |error_message|
        tag.span error_message, class: 'uk-text-danger'
      end

      tag.div class: 'uk-margin' do
        "
        #{@form.label(field, class: 'uk-form-label')}
        #{yield}
        #{errors.join(tag.br)}
        ".html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run this I get the error `NameError - undefined local variable or method 'tag' for #<FormHelper::StyledFormBuilder:0x00007ffa08141220>`
Is there a way to create a class inside a helper module with access to other helper methods? If not, how should I go about doing this "the right way"?

Comment: There's nothing special about FormHelper::StyledFormBuilder. Like any other object, you have to give it everything it needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the view context into the class:

```
# app/helpers/form_helper.rb
module FormHelper
  def styled_form_for(record)
    form_for record do |form|
      builder = StyledFormBuilder.new(form, context: self)

      yield form, builder
    end
  end

  class StyledFormBuilder
    
    def initialize(form, context:)
      @form = form
      @obj = form.object
      @context = context
    end

    def text_field(field, **props)
      styled_field :field do
        @form.text_field field, class: ['uk-input', @obj.errors[field].any? && 'uk-form-danger', *props.class],
                                **props
      end
    end

    private

    def styled_field(field)
      errors = @form.object.errors[field].map do |error_message|
        @context.tag.span error_message, class: 'uk-text-danger'
      end

      @context.tag.div class: 'uk-margin' do
        "
        #{@form.label(field, class: 'uk-form-label')}
        #{yield}
        #{errors.join(tag.br)}
        ".html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The view context is the context where all the view helpers and your helpers get mixed into and its the implicit self when rendering a view.

Comment: You might also want to use concat instead of using `.html_safe` especially as you don't really know how the method could be used and if the content really is safe. https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.
Could you send me docs about the "delegate" method? I'm having trouble understanding the usage.
Can you also explain the syntax in the "context:" parameter? Why the ":"?

Again, thanks a lot

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate I removed it in a edit though as its a bit too complex for the problem.

Comment: In `def initialize(form, context:)` - `:` creates a required keyword argument. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments